# C#: run-time datatype conversion

Tags: c#, dynamic, types

This is my first time using StackOverflow myself. I have found many answers to many of my question here before, and so I thought I would try asking something myself.

I'm working on a small project and I am a bit stuck right now. I know ways to solve my problem - just not the way I want it to be solved.

The project includes an NBT parser which I have decided to write myself since it will be used for a more or less custom variation of NBT files, though the core principle is the same: a stream of binary data with predefined "keywords" for specific kinds of tags. I have decided to try and make one class only for all the different types of tags since the structure of the tags are very similar - they all contain a type and a payload. And this is where I am stuck. I want the payload to have a specific type that, when an explicit conversion is done implicitly, throws an error.

The best I could come up with is to make the payload of type Object or dynamic but that will allow all conversions done implicitly:

```
Int64 L = 90000;
Int16 S = 90;
dynamic Payload; // Whatever is assigned to this next will be accepted
Payload = L; // This fine
Payload = S; // Still fine, a short can be implicitly converted to a long
Payload = "test"; // I want it to throw an exception here because the value assigned to Payload cannot be implicitly cast to Int64 (explicit casting is ok)
```

Is there any way of doing this? I would like to solve it by somehow telling C# that from now on, even though Payload is dynamic, it will throw an exception if the assigned value cannot be implicitly converted to the type of the current value - unless, of course, it is done explicitly.

I am open to other ways of accomplishing this, but I would like to avoid something like this:

```
public dynamic Payload
{
    set
    {
        if(value is ... && Payload is ...) { // Using value.GetType() and Payload.GetType() doesn't make any difference for me, it's still ugly
            ... // this is ok
        } else if(...) {
            ... // this is not ok, throw an exception
        }
        ... ... ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using generics?
This would automatically give you compile-time checking on which conversions are allowed.

```
class GenericTag<T>
{
    public GenericTag(T payload)
    {
        this.Payload = payload;
    }

    public T Payload { set; get; }
}

// OK: no conversion required.
var tag2 = new GenericTag<Int64>(Int64.MaxValue);

// OK: implicit conversion takes place.
var tag1 = new GenericTag<Int64>(Int32.MaxValue);

// Compile error: cannot convert from long to int.
var tag4 = new GenericTag<Int32>(Int64.MaxValue);

// Compile error: cannot convert from string to long.
var tag3 = new GenericTag<Int64>("foo");
```

Comment: This would actually be a pretty ingenious solution, however, I can't seem to get the syntax right. Instantiating with GenericType<Int64> works great, but the type is not static. When parsing NBT files the keywords for specific types are just single bytes. 1 means byte, 2 means short, 3 means int, 4 means long, and so on. So I thought I could make a Type[] object (let's call it Types) with the specific types in their corresponding indices, and then I would be able to instantiate with GenericTag<Types[INDEX]>, where INDEX is the byte code for the type, but I can't do that. Any ideas?

Comment: @maqhem Just make your array with `new Type[]{typeof(GenericType<byte>),typeof(GenericType<short>),typeof(GenericType<int>),typeof(GenericType<long>)}` then use `Activator.CreateInstance(Types[INDEX], value)`

Comment: @jbtule I didn't even think of that, of course that does the trick. Thank you both! I'll mark this answer as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will need Int64, why not to use Convert.ToInt64?

Comment: Because I don't know what type it will be. I have a list of 10 different types, and I know it's going to be one of them, but I don't know which one. Generic types seem to be a good way to do it although it kinda just gets me stuck somewhere else. I haven't done much with generic types before.